# VSCode show error after use PHP Intelephense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get post data from client, the code working fine until I switch to use PHP intelephense extension. It show that I have error "expected type 'object'. Found 'array'.intelephense(1006)"

my part of code that error is like ->

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && empty($_POST)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
}

$date = $_POST->date;
$branch = $_POST->idBranch;
```

The error part is at `$_POST`.

Is it error with the extension or is it my code that is not correct.

Comment: if the condition is not satisfied, `$_POST` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the $_POST in a wrong way.
The Intelephense think that $_POST should always use like this:

```
$_POST['something']
```